# MongoDB 2.4 unauthorized to setProfilingLevel with admin role

Tags: mongodb, admin, profile, unauthorized

I am the admin of a MongoDB 2.4 which is in production. When I am trying to activate profiling on some databases, it returns:

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }
```

all the other profile-related commands return also a sort of unauthorized error messages.

my admin roles and rights are as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "pwd" : "...", "roles" : [  "userAdminAnyDatabase",  "readWriteAnyDatabase",  "clusterAdmin" ], "user" : "admin" }
```

Do I need any other role to be able to profile, or there is another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the dbAdminAnyDatabase role:

> **dbAdminAnyDatabase**
>
> dbAdminAnyDatabase provides users with the same access to database
>   administration operations as dbAdmin, except it applies to all logical
>   databases in the MongoDB environment.

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/